# Replace newline in variable and change back in bash

Tags: bash

I'd like to replace all the new lines with the character `>` and then to the opposite again.

```
INPUT=..a lot of stuff

INPUT_ARROW=${INPUT/\\n\>}
INPUT_ORIGINAL=${INPUT/>\\\n}
```

It's pretty confusing syntax.

Comment: `INPUT_ARROW=${INPUT/...>}` doesn't modify `INPUT`, so there's no need for `INPUT_ORIGINAL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$'\n'` to represent newline:

```
echo "$s"
abc
123
foo
bar
p="${s//$'\n'/>}"
echo "$p"
```

```
abc>123>foo>bar
```

Now to change it back to newlines:

```
echo "${p//>/$'\n'}"
```

```
abc
123
foo
bar
```